# EditText.GetText, return exception about null reference, but it is declared

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android Application and I have some issues.

I have some EditText Inputs and I want to create an Object called Contest with the text from input. My code is the following:

```
package com.example.torge.projectnow.loginSystem;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.example.torge.projectnow.R;

public class AddContest extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Spinner sCategoryC = null;
    String idUserUpload = "1";
    EditText etContestName, etShorDesC, etDeadlineC, etAgeLimitC, etStartDateC, etLocatoinC, etFullDesC, etCostC;
    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
    Button bSendContest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_contest);
        sCategoryC = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sCategoryContest);
        etContestName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etContestName);
        etShorDesC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etShortDesC);
        etDeadlineC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDeadlineC);
        etAgeLimitC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAgeLimitC);
        etStartDateC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etStartDateC);
        etFullDesC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFullDescC);
        etCostC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCostC);



        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton bSendContest = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.bSendContest);
        bSendContest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Contest contest = new Contest(etContestName.getText().toString(),
                        sCategoryC.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        etShorDesC.getText().toString(),
                        etDeadlineC.getText().toString(),
                        etAgeLimitC.getText().toString(),
                        etStartDateC.getText().toString(),
                        etLocatoinC.getText().toString(),
                        etFullDesC.getText().toString(),
                        idUserUpload,
                        etCostC.getText().toString());

                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.bSendContest :
                        if(etContestName.getText().toString().matches("") ||
                                sCategoryC.getSelectedItem().toString().matches("") ||
                                etShorDesC.getText().toString().matches("") ||
                                etDeadlineC.getText().toString().matches("") ||
                                etAgeLimitC.getText().toString().matches("") ||
                                etStartDateC.getText().toString().matches("") ||
                                etLocatoinC.getText().toString().matches("") ||
                                etFullDesC.getText().toString().matches("") ||
                                idUserUpload.matches("") ||
                                etCostC.getText().toString().matches("")){
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddContest.this).create();
                            alertDialog.setTitle("Something went wrong");
                            alertDialog.setMessage("Please fill all the boxes");
                            alertDialog.show();

                        }else {
                            ServerRequest serverRequest = new ServerRequest(AddContest.this);
                            serverRequest.StoreContestInBackground(contest);
                            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.addProjectLayout), "The contest Succesfuly added!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(AddContest.this, Dashboard.class));
                        }

                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


    }
}
```

But i get this error

```
02-29 20:15:49.950 12260-12260/com.example.torge.projectnow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.torge.projectnow, PID: 12260
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.torge.projectnow.loginSystem.AddContest$1.onClick(AddContest.java:47)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4788)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19965)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5431)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

And I can't resolve it. Can you help me?

Comment: Which line is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialize your `etLocatoinC`

i.e

```
etLocatoinC=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLocatoinC);
```

and you are attempting to call getText() method on it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to cast the TextView `etLocatoinC`in the `onCreate` method, that is declared but null referenced...
and since you are calling the the getText in the onClick method, then you get a NPE..

## Quickfix:

```
etLocatoinC=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLocatoinC);
```